# Closest in meaning confusion

Tags: meaning, word-choice, single-word-requests, meaning-in-context

I am preparing for an exam and came across the following problems. Since my english is limited in knowledge i am posting it here.

The sentence: This nitrogen dioxide(NO2) **plays a role in** the formation of acid rain in wetter or more humid climates.

My question: The phrase **"plays a role in"** is closest in meaning to ?

My answer was **"acts the part of"**. My reason was that since NO2 is a required substance in acid rain, its a part of it.

But the real answer is **"serves a function in"**. How is this Possible? How can it be just a function when without it acid rain cannot happen?

Comment: Posting as comment, since it's not on-topic here: without N02, acid rain *can* happen. Sulfates can cause it too, right?

Comment: I don't like the "real answer" anyway. If *[substance]* **serves a function in** *[process]*, this implies to me that *[process]* is something deliberate and purposeful. By far the most common term in this context is **contributes to**, or if you want to emphasise that it's the *main contributor*, you could perhaps say it's **central to**. But the original exam question is presumably about chemistry, not language usage.

Comment: @Ernest: I'm no chemist, but I think the main cause of acid rain involves the *interaction* between sulphates and nitrogen oxides (of which NO2 may be the most important).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Acts the part of* is an incorrect interpretation, because it indicates that you are about to tell us which part the NO<sub>2</sub> will play.

What *plays a role in* indicates that NO<sub>2</sub> is playing a role, but is not about to tell us which. It is less specific.

Take these examples:

> Brad Pitt *acts the part of* Tyle Durden in Fight Club.

vs.

> Dame Helen Mirren *plays a role in* the film The Queen.

In the first you are directly indicating which role Brad Pitt plays, where as in the second you are indicating that a role is played, but not which one.

You could change the verb *play* to *act*, and it would mean the same thing in a theatrical context - *acts a role in* - but this is not normally used in more general contexts.

*Role* can be used as a synonym for *function*, e.g.

> The *function* of the bus driver is to drive the bus

or

> The *role* of the bin man is to collect the rubbish

*Serve* and *play* can be used synonymously in some circumstances, in yours it depends what kind of imagery you want to use. *Serving* drawing the image of a servant, whereas *playing* evokes that of an actor.

So the phrase *serves a function* indicates that NO<sub>2</sub> is doing something, but not what it is doing, much the same as *plays a role*. The main difference is that using *serves* has an implication of being under the control of someone, where as *plays* gives the NO<sub>2</sub> a more autonomous image.

Answer (score 1):

> My reason was that since NO2 is a required substance in acid rain, its a part of it.

That reasoning would instead justify "*acts **as** part of*". As you wrote it, you suggest "NO2" performs a role in some sort of screenplay, pretending to be "the formation of acid rain".

Regardless, that wouldn't work here because NO2 isn't a part of *the formation of* acid rain, but a part of the acid rain itself.

The phrase "plays a role in" also suggests "some sort of screenplay", but here the "formation of acid rain" is our 'screenplay', metaphorically.

> How can it be just a function when without it acid rain cannot happen?

A "function" absolutely can be essential to the entire process.